# React Native Packager run transform before finding dependencies

Tags: react-native, rex

I've been trying to create a module that makes it possible to define "aliases" for React Native modules. E.g. instead of

```
require('../../../../../MyModule');
```

we could write

```
require('MyModule');
```

and define an alias for this module with the correct location. I implemented a babel plugin that would do the trick, but it turns out the packager runs "*find dependencies*" before "*transform*", thus making the work done by my module ineffective. Is there a way to transform the files before bundling (or solve the problem in any other way)?